# db not initialising in sqflite - flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, mobile-development, sqflite

I am working with sqflite database in flutter for the first time, but am unsure where I am going wrong. I call the db initialiser, but I don't get the output after it has happeneed (success message). Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code that I have written:

**database_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

final String tableName = 'notification';
final String columnKey = 'ColumnKey';
final String columnNumber = 'ColumnNumber';

class NotifInfo{
  int number;
  String key;

  NotifInfo(
  {
    this.number,
    this.key,
}
      );

  factory NotifInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NotifInfo(
    number: json["number"],
    key: json["key"]
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() =>{
    "number": number,
    "key": key,
  };
}

class NotifHelper{
    static Database _database;
    static NotifHelper _notifHelper;

    NotifHelper._createInstance();
    factory NotifHelper(){
      if (_notifHelper == null){
        _notifHelper = NotifHelper._createInstance();
      }
      return _notifHelper;
    }

    Future<Database> get database async{
      if (_database == null){
        _database = await initialiseDatabase();
      }
      return _database;
    }

    static NotifHelper _notifhelper;



    Future<Database> initialiseDatabase() async{
      var dir = await getDatabasesPath();
      var path = dir + "noti.db";
      
      var database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (db, version){
        db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE $tableName ($columnKey STRING, $columnNumber INT)
        ''');

        db.execute('''INSERT INTO $tableName ($columnKey, $columnNumber) VALUES ("PrimaryKey", 1)''');
      });
      return database;
      
    }


    void insertNotif(NotifInfo notifInfo) async{
      var db = await this.database;
      var result = db.insert(tableName, notifInfo.toMap());
      print('result is: $result');
    }


}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:data_connection_checker/data_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:pravproj/db/database_provider.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'articles_class/articles.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';



//var value = gethttps();

class PravUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PravUIState createState() => _PravUIState();
}

class _PravUIState extends State<PravUI> {
  var data;
  bool connectivity = true;
  StreamSubscription<DataConnectionStatus> listener;

  Timer timer;
  int counter = 0;

  NotifHelper _notifhelper = NotifHelper();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _notifhelper.initialiseDatabase().then((value){
      print("------------Database Initialised----------------");
    });
    data = getData();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (Timer t) => addValue(connectivity));



  }
```

Comment: try to add a try ...catch inside the initialise Database, if the then(...) function is not call, then it should be raised an exception